# Getting an error trying to install Yii rights extension

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

i am trying to install rights extension in Yii, and getting following error.

> Alias "bootstrap.widgets.TbNavbar" is invalid. Make sure it points to
>   an existing directory or file.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

add this line in top in `protected/config/main.php`

```
Yii::setPathOfAlias('bootstrap', dirname(__FILE__) . '/../extensions/bootstrap');
```

this will make an alias witch you are using to bootstrap directory

**bootstrap**.widgets.TbNavbar

Comment: did to put bootstrap files under protected/extensions/ ? did you make sure you have a folder under /extensions/bootstrap/widgets/TbNavbar/ ?

Comment: i am using boilerplate and in backend i am not using Tbnavbar.
But it's giving error of tbnavbar

Comment: this error is suggesting that you have a line of code using it as reference, if you don't need it, remove it